# Android ExpandableListView with multiple CheckBoxes

Tags: android, expandablelistview

Здравствуйте.
Имеется ExpandableListView:

group:

```
<TextView android:id="@+id/childname"
    android:paddingLeft="50px"
    android:textSize="14px"
    android:textStyle="italic"
    android:layout_width="150px"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

item:

```
<TextView android:id="@+id/childname"
    android:paddingLeft="50px"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:textSize="14px"
    android:textStyle="italic"
    android:layout_width="150px"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="19"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp" />

<TextView android:id="@+id/rgb"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:textSize="14px"
    android:textStyle="italic"
    android:layout_width="100px"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1" />

<CheckBox android:id="@+id/check1"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"/>
```

Данные выгружаются с сервера и отдаются адаптеру типа ExpandableListActivity.
При выставлении флага на каком-нибудь элементе, после сворачивания/разворачивания группы чекбоксы проставляются у разных элементов.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это можно исправить. Мне нужно выставить флаги и получить список id-шников в виде idGroup+idChild

Comment: правильно организуйте ваш адаптер. Проблема в нем.